# Read xml from joining several files

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Hello i'm facing problem trying to parse a XPS printed file. I have a interleaving printed XPS file, and i want to parse this XML files, but the output is coming in pieces. i.e i have a [0].piece [1].piece [2].piece and [3].last.piece files and all them together represent the xml that i need to parse. do you guys have any idea what can i do to join all this files and transform them to a valid XML in order to be read it using .Net C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the files too big to simply read as text, join and then parse? That's the obvious solution that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use XDoc to read each file, then Linq To XML to select all of the elements you want.

[XDocument reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

EDIT: For the stream idea I put in my reply to your comment, this came up:

[Stitching together multiple streams in one Stream class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963483/stitching-together-multiple-streams-in-one-stream-class)

Comment: If you read each xml into an xmlDocument you will get an exception because each file separated is not a valid xml

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the problem. Off the top of my head, could you somehow use the stream input and when one file ends, move on to the second file, until the end? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349.aspx