# Add IV to beginning of CryptoStream

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm implementing local encryption within an existing file management program.

Much of the example code I can find, such as [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application), demonstrates how to write directly to a file, but what I need to do is provide a stream that is consumed elsewhere in the program:

```
CryptoStream GetEncryptStream(string filename)
{
    var rjndl = new RijndaelManaged();
    rjndl.KeySize = 256;
    rjndl.BlockSize = 256;
    rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rjndl.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    // Open read stream of unencrypted source fileStream:
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open); 

    /* Get key and iv */

    var transform = rjndl.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

    // CryptoStream in *read* mode:
    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read); 

    /* What can I do here to insert the unencrypted IV at the start of the
       stream so that the first X bytes returned by cryptoStream.Read are
       the IV, before the bytes of the encrypted file are returned? */

    return cryptoStream; // Return CryptoStream to be consumed elsewhere
}
```

My issue is outlined in the comment on the last line but one: how can I add the IV to the start of the CryptoStream such that it will be the first X bytes returned when the CryptoStream is read, given that control of when to actually start reading the stream and writing to a file is outside the scope of my code?

Comment: This is my encrypt method. The issue is prepending the IV when I don't have control of the utilization of the stream. The code above is based (loosely) on the MS code, the main difference being that I can't write directly to a file because I have to defer control of the streaming to other parts of the app that handle things like progress bars etc.

Comment: Both modes are valid, that's why they exist. I'm using Read mode because it's necessary in this case.

Comment: @xanatos No, it is an unencrypted stream. The author wants to supply a `CipherStream` in read mode that returns the ciphertext, with the other party controlling how/when it can be read out. Hopefully because it is in the same thread.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Now it is clear :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok... now that your problem is clear, it is "quite" easy... Sadly .NET doesn't include a class to merge two `Stream`, but we can easily create it. The `MergedStream` is a read-only, forward-only multi-Stream merger.

You use like:

```
var mergedStream = new MergedStream(new Stream[] 
{
    new MemoryStream(iv),
    cryptoStream,
});
```

Now... When someone tries to read from the `MergedStream`, first the `MemoryStream` containing the IV will be consumed, then the `cryptoStream` will be consumed.

```
public class MergedStream : Stream
{
    private Stream[] streams;
    private int position = 0;
    private int currentStream = 0;

    public MergedStream(Stream[] streams) => this.streams = streams;
    
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanSeek => false;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override long Length => streams.Sum(s => s.Length);

    public override long Position 
    { 
        get => position; 
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (streams == null)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(MergedStream));
        }

        if (currentStream >= streams.Length)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int read;

        while (true)
        {
            read = streams[currentStream].Read(buffer, offset, count);
            position += read;

            if (read != 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            currentStream++;

            if (currentStream == streams.Length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return read;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void SetLength(long value)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (disposing && streams != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < streams.Length; i++)
                {
                    streams[i].Close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            streams = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I added that as answer at the beginning of my answer, but note that the function in the question returns a `CipherStream` rather than just a `Stream`, which means that the code calling the function must still be refactored.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes With `Stream`s, partial reads are legal. If you try to read 100 bytes, the Stream can give you 1 byte out. Only if Read returns 0 bytes then the stream is finished.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good design to use a `CryptoStream` to communicate between two local parties. You should use a generic `InputStream` or pipe (for inter-process communication) instead. Then you can combine a `MemoryStream` for the IV and a `CryptoStream` and return the combination. See the [answer of xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448553/589259) on how to do this (you may still need to fill in the `Seek` functionality if that's required).

A `CryptoStream` will only ever be able to handle ciphertext. As you need to change the code at the receiver *anyway* if you'd want to decrypt you might as well refactor to `InputStream`.

---

If you're required to keep the current design then there is a hack available. First "decrypt" the IV using ECB mode without padding. As a single block cipher call *always* succeeds the result will be a block of data that - when encrypted using the `CipherStream` - turns into the IV again.

Steps:

1. generate 16 random bytes in an array, this will be the real IV;
2. *decrypt* the 16 byte IV using ECB without padding and the key used for the `CipherStream`;
3. initialize the `CipherStream` using the key and an all zero, 16 byte IV;
4. encrypt the "decrypted" IV using the `CipherStream`;
5. input the rest of the plaintext.

You will need to create an `InputStream` that first receives the decrypted IV (as `MemoryStream`) and then the plaintext (as `FileStream`) for this to be feasible. Again, [also see the answer of xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448553/589259) on how to do this. Or see for instance [this combiner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/combine-multiple-streams-in-a-single-net-framework-stream-o/) and [this `HugeStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963483/stitching-together-multiple-streams-in-one-stream-class) on good ol' StackOverflow.  Then use the combined stream as source for the `CipherInputStream`.

But needless to say hacks like these should be well documented and removed at the earliest convenience.

---

Notes:

- This trick won't work on any mode; it works for CBC mode, but other modes may use the IV differently;
- Note that an `OutputStream` would generally make more sense for encryption, there may be other things wrong with the design.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for those who've taken the time to answer. In the end I realized I have to have knowledge of the IV length in the buffering code, there's no way around it, so elected to keep it simple:

Encryption method (Pseudo-code):

```
/* Get key and IV */

outFileStream.Write(IV); // Write IV to output stream

var transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

// CryptoStream in read mode:
var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inFileStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

do
{
    cryptoStream.Read(chunk, 0, blockSize); // Get and encrypt chunk
    outFileStream.Write(chunk);             // Write chunk
}
while (chunk.Length > 0)

/* Cleanup */
```

Decryption method (Pseudo-code):

```
/* Get key */

var iv = inFileStream.Read(ivLength); // Get IV from input stream

var transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

// CryptoStream in write mode:
var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outFileStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

do
{
    inFileStream.Read(chunk, 0, blockSize); // Get chunk
    cryptoStream.Write(chunk);              // Decrypt and write chunk
}
while (chunk.Length > 0)

/* Cleanup */
```

Comment: I just *showed you a way to perform a workaround*. You then say it is not possible in this answer. Then you go *around* your own question by showing a general way of performing file encryption. And then you're *still not using an output stream for encryption or inputstream for decryption*.

Comment: Your code is also incorrect, read may not return all available bytes and at the end the `chunk` buffer will certainly not correct (unless the file contains exactly N * chunk size in bytes).

Comment: I thanked you for your input, marked my code clearly as pseudo-code, it works, and it does what I need it to do. I posted it here in the spirit of helping anyone else who came after me. No need to be snippy.