# Get IV from Encrypted text to use in decrypt method

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt using AES256 algorithm, I have the following code.

```
 public string Encrypt(string dataToEncrypt, string key)
            {
                if (dataToEncrypt == null || dataToEncrypt.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
                if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
                var iv = GenerateRandomNumber(16);
                using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
                    aes.IV = iv;
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, 
                       aes.CreateEncryptor(),
                            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                        cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();                    
                        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
  public string DecryptReturnsString(string dataToDecrypt, string key)
        {
            if (dataToDecrypt == null || dataToDecrypt.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dataToDecrypt");

            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
                byte[] data= Convert.FromBase64String(dataToDecrypt);
                aes.IV = getIV(data);
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(),
                        CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                    var decryptBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

                    return decryptBytes;
                }
            }
        }

   public byte[] GenerateRandomNumber(int length)
        {
            using (var randomNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var randomNumber = new byte[length];
                randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomNumber);

                return randomNumber;
            }
        }
        private static byte[] getIV(byte[] arr)
        {
            byte[] IV = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(arr, 0, IV, 0, 16);
            return IV;
        }
```

Here I am trying to Get the IV from the encrypted string, but the originally generated IV and the extracted IV are different when I was debugging, so its giving me this exception, "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

Can anyone please look at my GetIV() method and let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can't get the IV from the encrypted text.  You'll need to come up with some other way to pass it in.  Treat it like part of the encryption key; it's random value that ought to be transmitted securely.

Comment: The IV doesn't necessarily have to be secret. It's more similar to the salt for a hash where it has to be random and unique, but not necessarily secret if I understand it correctly. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/when-using-aes-and-cbc-is-it-necessary-to-keep-the-iv-secret

Comment: A common way to save the IV is to prepend it to the encrypted text. Therefore just write it to your `memoryStream` when encrypting. Then you can read it upon decryption.

Comment: Side note: `AesCryptoServiceProvider` has a predefined method called `GenerateIV()`. There's no reason to rebuild that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues.

1. Seems you are not sending IV along your ciphertext (it is not done itself) . Common practice is prepending the IV to the the ciphertext. So as Robert commented, you can write IVto the memory stream directly prior encryption
2. when decrypting, you can read the IV (first bytes of your *data*, but decrypt only the rest (sub-array 16 .. length )

Answer (score 1):

IV in CBC mode of operation the IV must be sent as unencrypted, otherwise, you cannot decrypt the first block, the rest can be decrypted. There is no security issue in this. For the CBC the crucial about the IV is that it must be unpredictable.

as Robert said, prepend it to the beginning of the stream.

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445749/add-iv-to-beginning-of-cryptostream)

```
var mergedStream = new MergedStream(new Stream 
{
    new MemoryStream(iv),
    cryptoStream,
}
```