# IEnumerable<Stream> to One big Stream or MemoryStream

Tags: c#, memorystream

I have IEnumerable streams. How do I convert this to a one big MemoryStream or byte[].
I want all the Stream inside streams appended into one big Stream/MemoryStream. We are having certain performance problems by iterating over all the streams. I am looking for an optimal solution.

```
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            foreach (var stream in streams)
                            {
                                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                            }
                            byteData = ms.ToArray();
                        }
```

Thank you

Comment: foreach and `Stream.CopyTo` to another stream, each copy will start at the current position, meaning it will keep growing

Comment: @TheGeneral:Updated question to show what I have. Is that the best  for performance?

Comment: The performance will be as good as the stream you are writing to, if its a memory stream it will be as performant as you can get without preallocating a buffer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stitching together multiple streams in one Stream class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963483/stitching-together-multiple-streams-in-one-stream-class)

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where taking multiple *separate* streams and combining them *in memory* will **fix** a performance problem; I can think of lots of scenarios where it will **cause** a performance problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-5.0)

> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does
> not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy
> operation is complete.

```
var list = new List<Stream>()
{
   new MemoryStream(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4}),
   new MemoryStream(new byte[] {5, 6, 7, 8}),
   new MemoryStream(new byte[] {9, 10, 11, 12})
};

var result = new MemoryStream();

foreach (var stream in list)
   stream.CopyTo(result);

var array =result.ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
```

**Output**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IEnumerable of VirtualStream instead of MemoryStream or FileStream
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14192551/

Basically when size goes beyond configured threshold it will auto create  FileStream. The files will get deleted after disposed